# zsh aliases doesn't work from .zshrc file

Tags: command-line, alias, zsh

I want to create an alias to mount some remote file systems locally. I placed lines like this in my `.zshrc` file:

```
alias remfs='sshfs rem: ~/mnt/sshfs/rem'
```

But when I run `remfs`, I get an error "command not found".

I also tried to put them in `.zshenv` without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have to restart your current Z shell or to source `.zshrc` file in the current Z shell session in order to make it work:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Also, `sshfs` must to be installed. If you don't have it installed, you can use the following command to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install sshfs
```

Comment: I closed the terminal and open a new one. Isn't that enough?

Comment: @Yotam Yes, it's enough. What exactly is the error that you receive? And this command: `sshfs rem: ~/mnt/sshfs/rem` is working if you run it as normally?

Comment: Well, after a reboot things work properly.